# Registry change isn't silent

Tags: powershell

When ran with elevated privileges, the code does what it is supposed to do by turning off the laptop's onboard microphone, but it needs to be totally silent.  This will be sent out to over 1600 systems.  It will be pushed via logon script to the local systems.  So it needs to run as Admin and without any user intervention.  How do I keep it running elevated and how to get it to run without the UAC prompt?

-TIA

```
$audioCaptureRegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture" 

$MICS = Get-Item $audioCaptureRegPath
$MICS.GetSubKeyNames() | % {`
    if($(Get-ItemProperty -Path $audioCaptureRegPath"\"$_).DeviceState -eq 1 ){`

    $systemNameData=$(Get-ItemProperty -Path $audioCaptureRegPath"\"$_\Properties).$systemNameVal
    if(!($systemNameData -match "plant") -or !($systemNameData -match "HDX"))
    {   
    $tmpFileFullPath = [System.io.Path]::getTempFileName()
    "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00" | Out-File -FilePath  $tmpFileFullPath -Append
    " " | Out-File -FilePath  $tmpFileFullPath -Append
    "[$($MICS.Name)\$_]" | Out-File -FilePath  $tmpFileFullPath -Append
    "`"DeviceState`"=dword:10000001" | Out-File -FilePath  $tmpFileFullPath -Append
    " " | Out-File -FilePath  $tmpFileFullPath -Append
    regedit.exe /S $tmpFileFullPath

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it as a startup script instead of a login script?

Comment: EBGreen is right, startup scripts run with elevated privileges where login scripts do not

Comment: I can look into the option of running as a startup script.  The only issue may be that the GPOs run at a level higher than I have access.

Comment: I bet you know someone that has access...

Comment: Why write a temporary file and run `regedit.exe` when you can set the value directly using `Set-ItemProperty`?

Comment: That's a good question... the location of each device state is under a different subkey on various systems.  This was written to be able to find the different key and change the device state dword value.  If there's another way to do it using Set-ItemProperty I would love the help.